Xcode 16: RealmSwift has a minimum deployment target of iOS 18.0
I'm building my app for the first time with the final release version of Xcode 16 (released today), but I'm getting an error saying:

Compiling for iOS 13.4 but RealmSwift has a minimum deployment target for iOS 18

This doesn't happen with Xcode 15, nor did it happen with any of the Xcode 16 Betas, nor the Xcode 16 RC, only with today's final Xcode 16.
Why is this happening. What can be done about it?

Can you include your podfile in the question please? You may need to change a setting in XCode as well. Need to see podfile first.

Update your realm version (pod update). It is helped me.

Update Podfile pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 10.0' beforehand, since Realm introduced version 20 with deprecated sync features. And update only the Realm version by running pod update RealmSwift.

Are you using Cocoapods or SPM? Including Realm as a Swift Package instead of a Pod fixed the issue for me.

Using it as a pod

Find Xcode -> Pods -> Targets -> Realm and type your compiling version in minimum deployment target.
In Xcode 15 there was no such problem, so it is possible to fix globally only by upgrading to the latest version of Realm

Or look for a POD file script that will do the minimum deployment target recording for you when you install the pods.

